# Inflate view with new child above all existing children

Tags: android, layout-inflater

Just getting exposed to `LayoutInflater` and its capabilities and came up with a silly question. I am working on a game layout in which the player makes an unknown amount of guesses, and I would like to inflate each new guess into `guessContainer` above all previous existing ones.

Relevant xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/guessContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
```

Relevant java:

```
private void addNewGuess(){
    ViewGroup guessContainer = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.guessContainer);
    View newGuess = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.guess_new, null);
    guessContainer.addView(newGuess);
}
```

The above code works as expected - each time `addNewGuess` is called, a new copy of `R.layout.guess_new` is generated below all the others. Is there a way to flip this behavior and use `LayoutInflater` to place new guesses on top of the others or am I thinking about this all wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `addView(View child, int index)`:

```
private void addNewGuess(){
    ViewGroup guessContainer = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.guessContainer);
    View newGuess = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.guess_new, null);
    guessContainer.addView(newGuess, 0);
}
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View,%20int)):

> index int: the position at which to add the child

Comment: The young need their parents. (So that they get the right LayoutParams.) `View newGuess = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.guess_new, guessContainer, false);`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to handle such behaviour.

What I would suggest is replacing that `LinearLayout` with a `ListView` or `RecyclerView` (which one suits you the best) and adding new items to adapter. 
That way you can control in which position you want your new item to be added.
Furthermore, having all your data in a list gives you more control over it (from my point of view).

Comment: I think this is a better answer, although @user13 's answer actually explains what this question asked. I don't know why this has got a down vote.

Comment: I am going to accept user13's answer, but you are right - I think a ListView is what I want. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! I still have a long way to go but things are slowly piecing together

Comment: Well, user13 did answer your question, I just gave a different solution. 
My main concern would always be to make sure that as much control of UI and data presented in it.